# Quicksort on doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, sorting, queue, quicksort

Hi guys im trying to build quicksort into my scheduler code using alghoritm found on the internet. My problem is that at some point of the code I get Access violation about getPrev, probably it points to null but I'm stuck and have no idea how to make it work. Would be thankful for any little help or at least advice in which direction shall I go. I have already spent hours on it and it makes no effect.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:

Node(int value, Node* nextptr = nullptr, Node* prevptr = nullptr, int     currentpriority = 0)
{
    this->value = value;
    next = nextptr;
    prev = prevptr;
    priority = currentpriority;

}

int getVal(void)
{
    return value;
}

Node* getNext(void)
{
    return next;
}

Node* getPrev(void)
{
    return prev;
}

void setVal(int value)
{
    this->value = value;
}

void setPrev(Node* prevptr)
{
    prev = prevptr;
};

void setNext(Node* nextptr)
{
    next = nextptr;
}

int getPriority(void)
{
    return priority;
}

void setPriority(int priority)
{
    this->priority = priority;
}

private:
Node* next;
Node* prev;
int priority;
int value;
};

class Stack
{
public:
Stack(void)
{
    top = nullptr;
}


~Stack(void)
{
    while (NodePop() != nullptr);
}

void Push(int value)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node(value, top);
    top = tmp;
}

Node* NodePop(void)
{
    Node* tmp = top;
    if (top != nullptr) top = top->getNext();
    return tmp;
}

int Pop(void)
{
    Node* tmp = NodePop();
    int ret = 0;
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        ret = tmp->getVal();
    }

    else
    {
        throw "Stack Empty";
    }
    delete tmp;
    return ret;
}

private:

Node* top;
};

class Queue
{
public:
Queue(void)
{
    back = front = nullptr;
}

~Queue(void)
{
    while (NodeDequeue() != nullptr);
}

void Enqueue(int i, int priority = 0)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node(i, back, nullptr, priority);
    back = tmp;
    if (front == nullptr) front = back;
    else
    {
        tmp = back->getNext();
        tmp->setPrev(back);
    }
}

int Dequeue(void)
{
    Node* tmp = NodeDequeue();
    int ret = 0;
    if (tmp != nullptr)
    {
        ret = tmp->getVal();
    }
    else
    {
        throw "Queue Empty";
    }
    if (front == nullptr) back = front; // queue now empty
    delete tmp;
    return ret;
}

protected:

Node* back;
Node* front;

private:

virtual Node* NodeDequeue(void)
{
    Node* tmp = front;
    if (front != nullptr)
    {
        front = front->getPrev();
        if (front != nullptr) front->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    return tmp;
}
};


class Scheduler : public Queue
{

public:
Node*getTail_Dll(Node*Head)
{
    if (Head != NULL)
    {
        while (Head->getNext() != NULL)
            Head = Head->getNext();
    }

    return Head;
}




 void partition_QuickSort_Dll(Node*Head, Node*Tail)
{
Node* NewTail=NULL,*Curr = Head, *Pivot = Tail;

    while (Curr != Pivot)
    {
        if ((Curr->getVal()) > (Pivot->getVal()))
        {
            if (Curr->getPrev() != NULL)
                Curr->getPrev()->setNext(Curr->getNext());
            if (Curr->getNext() != NULL)
                Curr->getNext()->setPrev(Curr->getPrev());

            NewTail = Curr;
            Curr = Curr->getNext();
            if (Curr->getPrev() == NULL)
                Head = Curr;

            NewTail->setPrev(Tail);
            NewTail->setNext(NULL);
            Tail->setNext(  NewTail);
        }
        else
            Curr = Curr->getNext();
    }

    if (Pivot->getPrev() != NULL)
        Pivot->getPrev()->setNext(NULL);

    if (Pivot->getNext() != NULL)
        Pivot->getNext()->setPrev(NULL);
}

 void quickSortList_Recur_Dll(Node*Head, Node*Tail)
{
    Node*Pivot = Tail;

    if ((Head != NULL) && (Tail != NULL) && (Head != Tail))
    {
        /* partition */
        partition_QuickSort_Dll(Head, Tail);
        /* sort left part */
        quickSortList_Recur_Dll(Head, (Pivot->getPrev()));
        /* sort right part */
            quickSortList_Recur_Dll(Pivot->getNext(), Tail);

        /* connect pivot to left & right parts */
        if (Pivot->getPrev() != NULL)
            Pivot->getPrev()->setNext(Pivot);

        if (Pivot->getNext() != NULL)
            Pivot->getNext()->setPrev( Pivot);  
    }
}

void quickSortList_Dll(Node*Head)
{
    Node*Tail = getTail_Dll(Head);

    if (Head != NULL)
        quickSortList_Recur_Dll(Head, Tail);
}
/*Node* split()
{

    Node *singleJump = back, *doubleJump = back;
    while (singleJump->getNext() && doubleJump->getNext()->getNext())
    {
        doubleJump = doubleJump->getNext()->getNext();
        singleJump = singleJump->getNext();
    }
    Node *temp = singleJump->getNext();
    singleJump->getNext()->setNext(nullptr);
    return temp;
}
*/


/*void antiBlock()
{
    cycle++;
    if (cycle == 5)
    {
        Node* temp = split();
        while (temp != front)
        {
            if (temp->getPriority() < 10)

                temp->setPriority(temp->getPriority() + 1);

        }
        cycle = 0;
    }
}*/
Node* NodeDequeue(void)
{
    Node* tmp = front;

    //antiBlock();
    quickSortList_Dll(back);
    if (front != nullptr)
    {
        front = front->getPrev();
        if (front != nullptr) front->setNext(nullptr);
    }
    return tmp;
}

};



int main()
{

Scheduler* s = new Scheduler;
s->Enqueue(11, 5);
s->Enqueue(2, 6);
s->Enqueue(3, 1);
s->Enqueue(40, 8);
s->Enqueue(15, 9);
s->Enqueue(6, 10);
//s->Enqueue(67, 6);
//s->Enqueue(78, 3);
//s->Enqueue(529, 2);
//s->Enqueue(110, 7);
//s->Enqueue(211, 4);
//s->Enqueue(312, 8);
//s->Enqueue(413, 3);
//s->Enqueue(154, 6);
//s->Enqueue(135, 2);
//s->Enqueue(116, 7);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    cout << s->Dequeue() << endl;


return 0;


};
```

Comment: is there a particular reason you are not using standard containers and algorithms?

Comment: yes, it is coursework, and we are required to stick to public API of Queue while creating the scheduler

Comment: When you used the debugger and single stepped through the code, which statement is presenting the issue?  Also, did you *watch* or print the value of the variables associated with the statement?

Comment: as i mentioned it is getPrev probably inside  partitionsort, I did watch and it seems that the problem tends to be inside partitionsort and quicksortlist_recur

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to use quicksort (not list "friendly")? If not, use a bottom up merge sort with array of pointers to the first nodes of a list. It's an old algorithm, but for some reason, it's not well known. It only uses forward (next) pointers and the typical MergeLists() that merges two already sorted lists, so it's list "friendly".

Example pattern, first node is stored in array[0]. second node is merged with array[0] to create a list of size 2 and stored in array[1] (array[0] is cleared). Two nodes later, a list of size 2 is merged with array[1] to create a list of size 4 and stored in array[2] (array[0], array[1] cleared). array[30] holds a list of size 1 billion (2^30). array[31] list size is unlimited, 1 billion nodes are merged into it at a time. So array size of 32 is overkill, but takes so little space that you might as well use it.

Wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Answer (score 0):

In `NodeDequeue`, I think you're calling `getPrev` on the first `Node`. The node before the first node should always be `null`. If you're removing the first node, you should set `first` equal to `first->next` and then set `first->prev` to `null`.

Comment: I'm certain this piece of code works, as NodeDequeue on its own works perfectly fine. It crashes when I implement the sorting algorithm. It cannot be the case as going step by step debugger does'nt go any further than quicksort call

Comment: Lets say there are 5 items in the queue. When you call `NodeDequeue`, you set `front` to `front->getPrev` which should always be NULL. Then in `Dequeue`, if `front == null`, you set `front=back`. So you removed 1 of 5 items but now you set `front` to null and set `back=front`.